# Catch Flask-KVSession timeout

Tags: python, flask, flask-kvsession

I need to be able to log when Flask-KVSession sessions time out. Is there a easy way to catch session timeouts and log when they occur?

Answer (score 1):

You can't know in real time. The session id is stored in a cookie, which is only sent by the browser when making requests. It won't send a cookie that has expired. KVSession won't load a session if it doesn't receive a valid cookie. There's no way to distinguish between a new session and an expired session because neither would send a cookie.

The extension does have a `cleanup_sessions` method, which will look through all the keys in the store and check if they're expired, but that must be called manually periodically, it's not an automatic process.

You can write a similar method to log before removing the expired sessions, but again you need to run this on your own schedule. The following is a copy of the `cleanup_sessions` method with logging added.

```
from flask import current_app
from flask_kvsession import KVSessionExtension as _BaseKVSessionExtension, SessionID

class KVSessionExtension(_BaseKVSessionExtension):
    def log_cleanup_sessions(self, app=None):
        if not app:
            app = current_app

        now = datetime.utcnow()

        for key in app.kvsession_store.keys():
            m = self.key_regex.match(key)

            if not m:
                continue

            sid = SessionID.unserialize(key)

            if sid.has_expired(app.permanent_session_lifetime, now):
                app.logger.info('Removing session %s', key)
                app.kvsession_store.delete(key)
```